# django sum of model objects and model field for related model as list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

What I need is query which will return a list of articles ordered by number which is calculated as sum of  foos.all + bar.peaces for article object. Here is how models looks:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

class Foo(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='foos')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userfoos')
    ...

class Bar(models.Model):
    article = models.OneToOneField(Article)
    peaces = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

So let say that `X` is article object:

```
foo_num = Foo.objects.filter(article=X).count()
bar_num = Bar.objects.get(article=X)
bar_num = bar_num.peaces
Y = bar_num + foo_num
```

So I need a list of articls ordered by `Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define my own sort method:

```
def article_sort(article_object):
     return len(article_object.foos.all()) + article_object.bar.peaces

def view():
    articles = sorted(Article.objects.all(), key=article_sort)
```

More information [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: Looks great but have error in view global name 'article_sort' is not defined

Comment: But after change to key=Artice.article_sort works as expected. Thanks Jeff